# How to Read a Large File Efficiently with Java/android

Tags: java, android, file

My android application receive a special file ( text file) from server in this format :

-----ZONE INFO------

// here text containing information about the received content

-----END ZONE-------

-----ZONE CONTENT--------

// full content

--------END ZONE---------

-------ZONE ADD------

//Additional details

------END ZONE-------

This is my using code to read file (line by line) and extract **INFO** and **CONTENT** and **ADDITIONAL DETAILS** to memory for doing some operations.

```
        String infoZone= "\t\t\t\t-------ZONE INFO-------";
        String contentZone= "\t\t\t\t-------ZONE CONTENT-------";
        String addZone= "\t\t\t\t-------ZONE ADD-------";
        String endZone= "\t\t\t\t-------END ZONE-------";
        BufferedReader reader;
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(receivedFile));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if(line.equals(infoZone)){
            while(!line.equals(endZone)) {
                line = reader.readLine();
                if(!line.equals("") && !line.equals(endZone) )
                    infoText+= line;
            }
        }
        line = reader.readLine();
        if(line.equals(contentZone)){
            while(!line.equals(endZone)) {
                line = reader.readLine();
                if(!line.equals("") && !line.equals(endZone) )
                    contentText+= line;
            }
        }
line = reader.readLine();
        if(line.equals(addZone)){
            while(!line.equals(endZone)) {
                line = reader.readLine();
                if(!line.equals("") && !line.equals(endZone) )
                    contentText+= line;
            }
        }
```

This code is working fine for small files, but when file size is bigger than 2 Mo, then the application became very slow ( it takes about 5 minutes to read all **CONTENT**).

Do you have any idea how to extract **INFO** and **CONTENT** efficiently ?

N.B : The maximum size of received file is 10 Mo.

Comment: Try specifying the size of the BufferedReader.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand your question, is it important to specify size in my case ? because i read line by line, so the default size is sufficient for me

Comment: reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(receivedFile), 3000000). Let me know if it works.

Comment: still same problem.. i dit it in other way, 
- get all data from file as a byte array.
-Data extraction from byte array.
For 6 Mo file about 1 min

Comment: Did you use a memory stream? I faced the same problem and read the entire data in a byte array in one go. I then created a memory stream instead of the FileStream. The rest of the code is the same. The improvement in performance was huge.

Comment: Good news, which memory stream did you used ? ByteBuffer ?

Comment: ByteArrayInputStream

Comment: Let me know if it works well